# multiple bitmaps versus drawables - performance and memory impact

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, android-drawable

As you can see on the screenshot, I'm showing thumbnails in the ListView on the left side. Those thumbs are generated asynchronously. Anyway, the result for each row/item is a new Bitmap.

[image: climbing wall management]

But I wonder if that's the best practise. This is because very often the background image (the climbing wall) is the same. Therefore I could generate a LayeredDrawable consisting of the background bitmap - which is the same for each row - and an own implementation of a Drawable which then draws the climbing route in its draw(Canvas) method.

Option 1: generate a new bitmap for each row/item.

Option 2: use a LayeredDrawable with the background bitmap and a dynamic Drawable.

Which option is best in terms of memory and CPU usage?

Comment: For memory, I would assume option #2 is better. For CPU, I would assume option #1 is better, as option #2 does everything option #1 does plus extra drawing.

Comment: I analyzed the memory and each of the thumbnails allocates about 307.000 bytes while the logical for a single climbing route (the line) including all line points allocates roughly 700 bytes depending on the number of points. Huge difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my purposes I'm using a custom drawable and a BitmapDrawable within a LayerDrawable. The bitmap is the background and the custom drawable draws the line and holds. If the underlying data of the drawn line changes, I'm setting a dirty-flag so that the drawable is re-drawn on next cycle.